# Reading a text file separated by commas into a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read a file of 5000 names into a 2D array in C which is formatted like this:

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET"
```

At the moment, it just gives me "segmentation fault:11". I am trying to read in each name to its own 2D array, but I can't figure out how to do this. This is my code so far:

```
//initialise array and chars
char names[5000][10] = {""};
int i;
char separator = ',';
char ch;

//open file
FILE *namesToBeSorted;
namesToBeSorted = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int j = 0;

//find file size
fseek(namesToBeSorted, 0L, SEEK_END);
int fileSize = ftell(namesToBeSorted);
rewind(namesToBeSorted);

//read from file into array
for (i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){
    fscanf(namesToBeSorted, "%c", &ch);
    while(ch != separator)
        names[i][j] = ch;
        fscanf(namesToBeSorted, "%c", &ch);
        j++;
}

//print array
for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("%c\n", names[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please convert your code to a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: _'At the moment, it just gives me "segmentation fault'_ So now's the time to learn how to use a debugger. That's a far better use of your and readers' time.

Comment: Note that `"PATRICIA"` is 11 characters including `\0`. You should scan for the quote, not the comma. And you have to add the `\0` to each name.

Comment: Apparently you don't care about the NUL terminators, ecach string needs to be terminated by a NUL (read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book). And are there any names longer than 9 characters?

Comment: Note also that `fileSize` is not acurate with reading in translated mode (Windows) because `0xd0xa` gets translated to a single `\n`. Better scan until `fscanf` returns EOF.

Comment: 1. You do not need to know the size of the file.
learn about `while (...) {....}` and `do {...} while(...)` loops

2. Learn about another functions which can help you read the character form the file. using scanf is an overkill.

Comment: Notice that the body of `for (i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){` keeps incrementing `j`, never reseting it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try summerize the issues from the comments and some input of my own...

Each field in `names` need to be one character longer than that of the longest name. If you know max size in advance just hard code it. Otherwise you need to make sure the number of read characters does not exceed the buffer you are inserting the string into. Lets leave that to another question; hard code something huge (e.g. 128 instead of 10), optimize later.

You are missing angle brackets to scope the body of `while(ch!=separator)`. C is not like Python where indentation is same as scoping.

`scanf` can be used to extract part of a string. Iterating through each character by yourself is not necessary. Not sure if this works but it should skip one character (`"`) and then extract characters until an occurance of `"`, skip a `,`, and repeat until all names have been extracted:

```
while(fscanf(namesToBeSorted, "\"%s\",", names[i++])); // terminates when fscanf fails to extract a name, see fscanf doc about its return value
i--; // adjusting counter. hacky hacky
```

`scanf` is your friend. With this solution there is no need of `fileSize`.

Print the string instead of the characters. Otherwise you will be printing characters not set for names shorter than max. Also, better use `puts` if printing a single string and want newline automatically:

```
while(i--) puts(names[i]);
```